# How do I set up an ssh tunnel to get server data from a whitelisted IP to feed into a local build?

Tags: networking, ssh, tunnel

It's possible this has been answered and my n00biness is preventing me from understanding the answers...

I'm working remote. I have a local build that I run on 127.0.0.1:8080. This build needs to get data from a remote DB. The remote DB only allows certain IPs to connect. I have another server that is whitelisted. So, I need to set up a tunnel to my whitelisted server to get the DB data, send that data back to my local build.

I can set up a tunnel so all my web traffic goes through my whitelisted server but then I can't access my local build anymore. Or I can run my local build but I can't use it because it thinks the server is disconnected.

I'm comfortable with Terminal I'm just not sure how to set it up so that I only get the server info back (and connect that to my local build) rather than all web traffic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can help you to connect your local build (Server-Software-Application?) to a local port, which is a tunnel to your database server.

You should be able to connect to your localbuild via browser on port 8080 while your Server-Software-Application is connecting to the database server, which can be reached by a ssh-tunnel via the whitelisted server.

If this is, what you want, I can help you with the following ...

I assume you can connect via ssh from your local build to your whitelisted server and that you can configure your database connection in your local build.

1. connect to your whitelisted server
2. configure a tunnel from whitelisted server to the database server
3. configure your local build to connect to 'localhost'

*Step 1. + 2.* can be done in one cli command:

```
ssh -L <any-number-gt-1024>:<database-server-ip>:<database-server-port> <your-username>@<whitelisted-server>
```

**Example:**

For a PostgreSQL database server which accepts connections on port 5432 with ip 192.168.1.20 and the whitelisted server with the ip 192.168.1.30 you can configure the tunnel like this:

```
ssh -L 1155:192.168.1.20:5432 heino@192.168.1.30
```

If this ssh connection is established you got a tunnel from your localbuild (from where the ssh connection is initialized) to the database server via the whitelisted server. You can talk to the database by connecting to 'localhost:1155'

```
telnet localhost 1155
```

Now you can configure your localbuild to connect to localhost on port 1155 to connect to the database server.

*Explination*

You connect to your whitelisted server by

```
ssh heino@192.168.1.30
```

To configure a tunnel which is reachable on localhost (thats the -L parameter) and connects to the database-server via whitelisted server you need to put the name / ip and the port by which the database server could be reached from the whitelisted-server in the parameters for the ssh connect. This also works with DNS Names or /etc/hosts entries.

```
-L 1155:<DB-Server>:<DB-Port>
```

PostgreSQL listen on Port 5432 by Default.
MySQL : 3306
...

*Step 3:*

configure your server-software-app to connect to localhost:1155 (or any port you choosed) and use the db-login-account from your whitelisted server.

**Notes**

- You should use a port on the localhost, that is not in use. But you should be warned by ssh, if the port is already in use.
- take care off your sql commands you send to the DB (e.g. DROP and TRUNCATE). You are sending this commands not to your localhost db but to the database server which you reach by the ssh tunnel! This is not your local build database if the tunnel is up and running.
- This Tunnel-Setup also works with all other reachable ports. Usefull for localhost-only-listening Tomcat-Admin-Manager-App etc.

Comment: Thanks, Heino. I won't have a chance to try this for a day or two but reading through it, it makes sense logically anyhow. We'll see what trouble I run into.

Comment: Sorry it took so long to accept your answer. I created the account just to ask this question and by the time I got around to trying it out I couldn't for the life of me figure out how to log back in. This multiple accounts thing across the multiple *exchange sites is crazy.